# How I can run init scripts as non-root user?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal

I put this file in /etc/init/proxyserver.conf that execute this script at startup (Ubuntu 11.10):

```
description "Run code for ProxyServer"
start on runlevel [23]

script
    cd /home/mark/selenium-client
    exec java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
end script
```

This works fine but if I execute this in the terminal:

```
ps aux | grep selenium
```

It return this screen:

```
root  783   0.0   2.3  680584   23688   ?   Ssl   Apr18   4:45   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
```

But I want to run the script as non-root user, how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `su` to run it as whatever user you want. You still would need root to set that up tho i think

Answer (score 5):

You could run it in [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) with the @reboot option

crontab -e to open up the user crontab.

add the line `@reboot /path/to/script` and it should start up your script on reboot as that user

Some more examples of [cron use here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use e.g.

```
sudo -u mark exec java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
```

to use the root privileges to execute the process as a specified user.

---

**EDIT:** Or perhaps

```
exec sudo -u mark java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
```

depending on what `upstart` wants (I don't use it myself).

Answer (score 2):

In Upstart, use the [`setuid`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) keyword:

```
description "Run code for ProxyServer"
start on runlevel [23]

setuid mark
chdir /home/mark/selenium-client
exec java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
```

(`script` is unnecessary.)

Alternatively, create a [user job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job) instead of a system one.